# Issue in sub domain access in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a this `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.domain.de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^$   folderName/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*)  folderName/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.domain.de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://admin.domain.de/admin-panel/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^$   admin-panel/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*)  admin-panel/$1 [L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule    ^$   folderName/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*)  folderName/$1 [L]
```

Hear I need to access sub-folder when the user access `domain.de` and it works fine with this.

As you can see I have another 2 sub-domain.

```
api.domain.de and admin.domain.de
```

**Issue:**

When I hit URL `admin.domain.de` then I will redirect me on `domain.de/folderName`, Instead of that it should redirect me on `http://admin.domain.de/admin-panel/`.

**Note:**

When I hit `admin.domain.de/admin-panel` then it works fine.

Can anyone help me and show me what is wrong in my `.hraccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.domain.de
 RewriteRule    ^$   admin-panel/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*)  admin-panel/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.de
 RewriteRule    ^$  foldername/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*)  foldername/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```